# Is this a good summary of real analysis up to Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm close to finishing my first semester of real analysis, and I've made the following broad stroke summary of everything leading up to the Taylor series.

Hopefully it's not completely off the mark...

#### Set of all functions mapping reals to reals

$$F \ni \forall f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$\downarrow$$

#### Set of functions that have a limit at point $c$

$$F \supsetneq F_1 \ni f: \lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$$
$$\downarrow$$

#### Set of functions that are continuous at $c$

$$F_1 \supsetneq F_2 \ni f: \lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)$$
$$\downarrow$$

#### Set of functions that are differentiable at $c$

$$F_2 \supsetneq F_3 \ni f: \exists f^\prime(x) = \lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}$$
$$\downarrow$$

#### Set of functions that are differentiable $n$ times at $c$

$$F_3 \supsetneq F_4 \ni f: \exists f^{(n)}(x)$$
$$\downarrow$$

#### Set of functions that are analytic at $c$

$$F_4 \supsetneq F_5 \ni f: f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n$$

Questions:

1. Can I declare, as I did, that functions of each step are a subset of the previous one
2. Have I missed any real function attributes crucial to making this funnel accurate?
3. Any false statements here?
4. Math typos?

Comment: Perhaps reword *Set of functions that converge at point* $c$ to *Set of functions that have a limit at point* $c.$

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? Up until this moment, I thought that it was :) @DaveL.Renfro

Comment: Everything here is correct as far as I can see:) You could have included the family of infinitely many times differentiable functions between $n$-times differentiable and analytic.

Comment: The change makes it seem less likely that you're talking about the convergence of a sequence of functions. Also, I think "converge at point $c$" isn't really correct terminology anyway. We speak of the convergence of sequences (of numbers, of points in some more general space, of functions, etc.), but what you're talking about is the limit of a function at a point.